# Receptacle wires

Tags: wiring

Is my receptacle box size big and deep enough to hold all these wires? [image: receptacle 4x 2 1/8 enter image description here]. This is for residential home built 40 yrs ago. Also what is the difference between this and a square box? I know that NEC has it requirements and this is how I found it when trying to replace a new tamper resistance receptacle." What would you suggest if it is over the requirements. Do I need to get a deeper box same size or ????also there is another two wires in the far right upper corner that is connected with a wire nut! Please note I disconnected one of these wire nuts because different gauges were mixed.

Comment: Can you give the gauge of each wire in the box, and the dimensions of the box please?

Comment: On casual inspection, as (apparently) a single-gang box that's not noticeably very deep, way too many wires for the cubic inches. Unless it's a square box with a single-gang mud-ring on it. (i.e. the box is much larger up/down than the hole that we can see) and even then it might be too much.

Comment: @Ecnerwal it kinda looks like it *actually is* that, noting the hole pattern in the back of the box. Aside from the rule, I doubt you could *physically* fit all those wires in a 1-gang box!  OP: don't shorten any, shortening them (these) doesn't help with the rule.  The rule only requires more cubic inches if they exceed certain thresholds of length.

Comment: 12 and 14 ga neutral (will change that too). The unscrewed wire nut are two reds are 12 and the blacks are a 12 and a 14 ga that I disconnected.  The two hidden wires connected by a wire nut that you can't see are 14 ga. The box is 4x2 1/8 x 2 1/8.

Comment: In all I have 6 12 ga and 6 14 ga. Copper wire.

Comment: Your right it is a single gang box. I have five conduit  going into it. I have rooom to go up and down or further back. Really don't want to make it a double gang box unless I have too. What do you suggest. I'm sure that most of my neighbors have similar problems. Thanks again.

Comment: @larrypinsky It has a 1-gang **face**, but it looks like behind it, the space opens up into a 2-gang box.

Comment: Harper it is really a handy type receptacle which raco doesn't make this type any longer. Thank u

Answer (score 1):

Let's see.  The largest wire in the box is 12 AWG, so all the grounds together count as one 12 AWG wire, so 2.25 inches.   Pigtails are free.

Six 12 AWG wires counts as 2.25 cubic inches each, so 13.5 cubic inches.  Six 14 AWG wires count as 2.00 cubic inches each, so 12 cubic inches.

One receptacle yoke counts as 2 of the largest conductor that goes to it - since that's 12AWG that counts as  4.5 cubic inches.  So let's see:

```
 2.25 cu. in. - grounds
 0    cu. in. - pigtails
13.5  cu. in. - six 12AWG wires (2.25 each)
12    cu. in. - six 14 AWG wires (2.00 each)
 4.5  cu. in. - 1 receptacle (2 x largest conductor going to it)
32.25 cu. in. TOTAL
27.75 cu. in. TOTAL if you omit receptacle
```

Now what's available to supply that? It *really* looks to me like a 4" square box (which come in 1.25, 1.5 or 2.125" deep) plus a 2-to-1-gang plaster ring front.   I really don't believe you have a 1-gang box because those wires just wouldn't fit at all.

- A 4x4 x 1.5" deep box is 21 cu. in.
- A 4x4 x 2.125" deep box is 30.30 cu. in.
- A 2-to-1-gang plaster ring of that sort is 3.3 cu. in.
- A 2-gang raised cover is 7.5 cu. in.
- A 1.5" box extension is 21 cu. in.

If you have a 2.125" deep box, with the ring you have 33.60 cubic inches, just enough.

However if you have a 1.5" box you are at 24.3 cu.in., considerably shy of the required.  Eliminating the receptacle would suffice if you added a 2-gang raised cover.  If you want to retain the receptacle, visit a *real* electrical supply house, and tell them your problem, and they can get you a cover plate that'll work. It may stick out from the wall just a bit.

Comment: Harper did as you suggested. Deleted it. I was wrong pure and simple. Will try to go to a regular electrian store. Also will ask more thoughtful and precise questions if given the opportunity. Anyways thanks for all of your help. Take care.